# Talend and character encoding

Tags: mysql, etl, talend, collate

I am using talend to transfer data from old database to new database. Old database is PostgreSQL and new one is MySQL.

But I have problem, because in old database there are these rows:

```
id      lft     rgt     rank_id    name_sci
------------------------------------------------------
6530    6137    6138    88         Ocythoë tuberculata
6340    6127    6128    88         Ocythoe tuberculata
```

**Mind the two dots above `e`**

So I have

```
tPsqlInput --> tFilterRow --> tMap --> tMysqlOutput
```

However, I am getting error: `Duplicate entry 'Ocythoe tuberculata' for key 'bio_taxons_name_sci_unique'`
If I put `tLogRow` component just before inserting into MySQL, i get correct output: `Ocythoë tuberculata` and `Ocythoe tuberculata`;

I have tried to directly insert into database:

```
into bio_taxons (name_sci, created_by, taxonomic_rank_id ) values ('Ocythoë', 1, 10);
```

And it works, and insertes that e with dots correctly, and when I do `SELECT` it shows that it has successfully inserted above row.

But from talend, for some reason it replaces `ë` (`e` with two dots) with ordinary `e` (without dots).

And i do not know how to solve this. I have tried editing MySQL connection but nothing seems to work:

Here's the current mysql connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://:3306/fis?noDatetimeStringSync=true&characterEncoding=Cp1252
```

I have tried with values "utf8", "utf-8", "latin1" "utf8mb4" but none of it worked...

Also in mysql:

```
mysql> SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| latin1                   | latin1_swedish_ci    |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using utf8 character set and corresponding collation across the board, so that you accommodate for every character (If you also need emoji go for [utf8mb4](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)).

In order to convert your database to UTF8:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

You may also need to change server encoding if it's not already in utf8. Check it with:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name LIKE 'char%'
```

Then instruct the JDBC driver to use utf8 enconding. Your connection string becomes:

```
jdbc:mysql://:3306/fis?noDatetimeStringSync=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Comment: I have only executed `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` and changed JDBC connection string, and it works, thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I was of help ;)

Comment: Hey, the problem in the question is solved, but there is another one, it changes letter `č` to `?`, but tLogRow component shows correct string in the output...

Comment: I'm terribly sorry I've missed your comment; were you able to solve your problem ?

Comment: yes, it was problem with my connection string, somehow I have changed it to default xD

Comment: Ok, I'm glad ;)